# How can we know that android project builded from support or androidx library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

As the title of this question, I'm going to import two difference maven library to my library poject,

At the same way,I'm going to provide two types dependencies, the one is `android support`, and the one is `androidx`

My Question is:

Is there any flags that let me know `androidx` or `android support` used? like bekow code snippet:

```
 if(isUsedAndroidx){
    implementation "library of androidx"
 } else {
    implementation "library of android support"
 }
```

The flag `android.useAndroidX` is work for this feature? like below:

```
if (android.useAndroidX !=null && android.useAndroidX.toBoolean()){
    print "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx used useAndroidX"
} else {
    print "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx used used android support "
}
```

Comment: I have found a way to do this, `project.hasProperty("android.useAndroidX")`